# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Domain\\Domain Users") takes forever

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, active-directory, httpcontext

Determined this can't be a network issue. I'm having this issue in debug (VS2012 / .Net 4.5 / IIS Express 8.0)

Code:

```
        bool rtn2 = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("MyDomain\\Domain Users");
```

Eventually returns true. But, can take several minutes.

```
        var test = HttpContext.Current;
        var test2 = HttpContext.Current.User;
        var test3 = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
```

...all extremely fast.

```
        var test = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("MyDomain\\Domain Users");
        var test2 = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("MyDomain\\Domain Users");
```

First call takes several minutes, the second is instant. If I change the second to look for some other group (assuming the first was cached), it is still instant.

I thought maybe i'm having network issues (I connect to the domain and debug over VPN.) However, if I create a new VS2012 web project and put that code in the startup page, it's instant. I can also search Active Directory from my machine and pull up the Domain Users group and see all people in it pretty much instantly (there are over 10 thousand users) - no problem. So, this must be project / config based issue?

Going out of my mind trying to figure this out. Some info:

Tried re-installing IIS Express
I've tried rebooting
I've tried in a new tester web project - works instantly

Problem seems to be machine specific. Any assistance or even just recommendations for additional trouble-shooting steps would be appreciated.

Comment: The second call is faster because the information is cached.

Comment: Then why is it faster after checking some other group? Surely the entire AD database isn't getting cached.

Comment: Something that came to mind, maybe you have an environment problem. If you had a faulty domain controller in DNS, that could possibly cause timeouts which might randomly cause LDAP connections to be slow. Is the 1st query slow every single time?

Comment: Yup - extremely consistent. Same thing on my tester project. It's extremely consistently fast. All I did was create a new web project with a single page.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace instead.

```
public static bool IsUserGroupMember(string userName, string groupName)
{
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName))
    using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
    {
        return groups.OfType<GroupPrincipal>().Any(g => g.Name.Equals(groupName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot faster. But now I have a couple of questions.

1. Why would this be blazing fast but searching from the httpcontext be slow?

2. Why would this be the case for only some projects where as if I create a new project both methods are fast.

3. Finally, what is the main difference between using this namespace and the previous? I realize this wasn't available until .net 3.5 and FYI: I've already this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @maplemale I wish I could tell you. I write applications that interact with AD at work and I've tried every which way possible to find the best method. The `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace i still not as fast as using the old `System.DirectoryServices` stuff for alot of things, but when it comes to this kind of thing its extremely easy to use and more than quick enough for most applications. I suggest my code could easily be improved, especially if you need to check more than one group. Maybe someone else can explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  IsInRole was taking forever to finish on a production server.  The following code worked instead.  Saw it somewhere, unfortunately can't remember the source.

```
// Is in AD Group?
private static bool IsInADGroup(String inGroup)
{
    foreach (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference group in
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
    {
        String sGroup = (group.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());
        if (sGroup.Equals(inGroup))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```